# openshift jersey not working

Tags: openshift, jersey-2.0

I am trying to execute a simple example of Jersey using openshift however i am running into a snag. I get error below:

```
2014/06/12 13:06:44,060 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) JBWEB000289: Servlet jersey-serlvet threw load() exception: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1298) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193) [jersey-core-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:766) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:488) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556) [jersey-server-1.8.jar:1.8]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:242) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) [jbossweb.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1100) [jbossweb.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:3591) [jbossweb.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3798) [jbossweb.jar:7.3.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:156) [jboss-as-web.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-3]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:93) [jboss-as-web.jar:7.3.3.Final-redhat-3]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_55]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
2014/06/12 13:06:44,356 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 35) JBAS018559:    Deployed "ROOT.war" (runtime-name : "ROOT.war")
2014/06/12 13:06:44,496 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.12.197.129:9990/management
2014/06/12 13:06:44,497 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.12.197.129:9990
2014/06/12 13:06:44,498 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.2.3.GA (AS 7.3.3.Final-redhat-3) started in 26318ms - Started 211 of 355 services (141 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Any idea what I can do to fix this?
I also have the repository posted here: https://github.com/bibhor/jerseyopenshift

Comment: Does this work in your local development environment?

Comment: yes. this works locally when i run it on my tomcat.